# Alternate Greek symbols

Tags: symbols, greek

I remember there being a way to display some Greek letters in a slightly different style (like how people often write Greek letters a bit differently than they're printed). Can anybody remind me of the command for this?

Comment: You can use \usepackage[Polutoniko, greek]{babel} and \textgreek{giannis} or are you looking for math fonts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\varphi`, `\varepsilon` and so on.

If you want to use one variant throughout and save yourself a few keystrokes, put `\let\phi\varphi` in your preamble.

The [`kpfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/kpfonts) package contains slanted and upright greek letters for mathmode.

[`psgreek`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/greek/psgreek/) provides some alternate Greek fonts.

Comment: I've been looking for a variant of $$\lambda$$, any thoughts?

Comment: You say "and so on" but a lot of these don't exist right? For example `\vardelta` does not.

Answer (score 19):

There are several packages that render slightly different Greek letters, such as the `upgreek` package.

[image]

You can check this and many more in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol Guide](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), starting from page 90.

Comment: very nice library, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I came across this document: http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf, which is a review of different fonts for math mode. In the document it also shows the rendered version of each of the fonts, to give you an impression of what the final result will be like.